# how to call function after two different event complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to initialize cropper plugin in modal pop up. Whenever user click on image uploader I want to show that image in popup and it should initialize cropper plugin when modal pop up finishes its show animation as well as after image loaded completely.

Currently what is happening sometime initCroping function get called before image loaded and sometime it calls properly.
I want to call initCroping function after image loaded and after changing $("#crop-img") src, Finally it should check if modal pop up loaded completely then it should fire iniCroping function.

both events are unpredictable sometime modal pop up comes first sometimes image loads. I want to check both the event complete and then initCroping should call.

Is there any easy way to call function after these two events complete.

```
$('#cropModel').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      //initCroping();

  });


$(".upload").change(function(e){

    var preview = $('#crop-img');
    var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      //preview.src = reader.result;
      $(preview).attr("src",reader.result);
      initCroping();
    }, false);

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simpliest method:

```
var counter = 2;
function fireInitCroping() {
    --counter === 0 && initCroping();
}

$('#cropModel').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      fireInitCroping();
});


$(".upload").change(function(e){

    var preview = $('#crop-img');
    var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
    var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      //preview.src = reader.result;
      $(preview).attr("src",reader.result);
      fireInitCroping();
    }, false);

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Screw-FileReader](https://github.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader) and a few promises works too

```
var shownPopup = new Promise(resolve => 
  $('#cropModel').one('shown.bs.modal', () => resolve())
)

var loadedImage = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  $(".upload").change(e => {
    // create a new Image obj from Blob that resolves/reject onload or onerror
    e.target.files[0].image().then(img => {
      img.id = "crop-img"
      $("#crop-img").replaceWith(img)
      resolve()
    } err => {
      console.error('not an image')
      reject(err)
    })
  })
})

// When both event's has fired then fire initCroping
Promise.all([shownPopup, loadedImage]).then(initCroping)
```